# fadeOut, addClass to background then fadeIn

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm trying to add fade in and fade out effect to a change of background of a div that lies fixed under the main content, so when the user clicks the buttons for certain content, the background changes with it: this works.

I tried to add CSS transitions but Firefox doesn't seem to support them for background change.

Then I tried this code but doesn't make what I need. I think I'm missing something, can you suggest a better sequence so the backgrounds change softly? I tried also with `delay(1000)`, but again, fails to fade the changed backgrounds.

What is the problem? the change of image happens right after the click, before the fadeOut.

```
jQuery('.button').click(function() {
    jQuery('#home-wrapper').fadeOut(999);
    jQuery('#home-wrapper').removeClass('default_background');
    jQuery('#home-wrapper').addClass('filter_music').fadeIn(999);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the callback parameter of `fadeOut` so that the class is changed *after* the animation ends. Try this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.button').click(function() {
        $('#home-wrapper').fadeOut(999, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('default_background').addClass('filter_music').fadeIn(999);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks it helped me to understand better how to write the code.